# Is there Alpakka SOAP support?

Tags: soap, apache-camel, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I have an application written in Scala/Akka and trying to add SOAP support. Anyone did it with Alpakka? Or what is the best way to do it. So far I think Camel is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Alpakka does not support SOAP, but there is an open [ticket](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/issues/176). Your best bet is probably to use Camel integration in your Scala/Akka project. To that end, take a look at the [streamz](https://github.com/krasserm/streamz) project or the [Camel integration](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/camel.html#introduction) module in Akka (the latter is deprecated but may serve your needs).

There is also a [library](https://github.com/playframework/play-soap) that provides some SOAP integration with Play.

Comment: Thanks, I think so too.